# 2DArray Structures algorithms

Tags: java

I'm am trying to get a output of:

1    2    3    4    5    6    7

8    9   10   11   12   13   14

15   16   17   18   19   20   21

In my for loop I am using r<21 but I get a exception at 3 which means i'm going past the row limit. how do I fix it :/

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class ArrayAlgorithms{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Environment();
}}


class Environment
{
    private int[][] table;

    Environment()
    {
        populate();
        output();
    }

    public void populate()
    {
        table = new int[3][7];
        for(int r=0;r<21;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
            table[r][c]= r + c;
        }
    }

    public void output()
    {
        out.println();
        for(int r=0;r<table.length;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
            out.print(String.format("%2d",table[r][c]) + "  ");
            out.println();
        }
        out.println();
        out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: In `for(int r=0;r<21;r++) {...}`, how many times does the loop body (the `...`) run, and what is the value of `r` on the last run?

Comment: I know r should start at 1 in the for loop but when i did that I got all 0s on the first 0.

Comment: Java is not `C`. It's 2D arrays are arrays of arrays (as references).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when calling the populate method is because the array you declare has dimensions of [3] and [7]. That means there is 3 "rows" and 7 "columns", however your main for loop is going outside the "row" dimension as it is trying to loop up to (but not including) the value of 21.

Modifying the main for loop in the populate method to `for(int r=0;r<3;r++)` will rectify your runtime issue.

However, to achieve the output you're expecting you need to fix the logic you have where you set the value of each array object. Try this instead: `table[r][c]= r*7 + c+1;`

Answer (score 2):

The size of the table is [3][7]. That means that r must be anywhere between zero and 2, inclusive. Try this

```
 public void populate()
    {
        table = new int[3][7];
        for(int r=0; r<table.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
            { 
                 table[r][c]= r*7 + c+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While you are absolutely right, your *between* could be misleading, since it should be inclusive of the beginning and exclusive of the end.

Comment: It worked! Thank you chessprogrammer. I'll be studying on error I had how I can improve my work. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `populate` method,

```
table = new int[3][7];
for(int r = 0; r < 21; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < table[0].length; c++) {
       table[r][c] = r + c;
    }
}
```

You can't loop over 21 if you initialized the length of the first array to `3`. This is why you get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`, when the loop tried to set the value of `table[3]` it failed because you initialized 3 values (index 0,1,2).

Instead use

```
for(int r = 0; r < table.length; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < table[0].length; c++) {
       table[r][c] = r + c;
    }
}
```

Like you use in the `output` method.